# Java abstract field pattern

Tags: java, oop, abstract

I'm not really sure how to describe this pattern that i want, but I would like something like this:

```
public abstract class Parent {
    protected abstract boolean foo = false; //this doesn't compile
}

public class Child1 extends Parent {
    protected boolean foo = true;
}
```

how do i do this?

Imagine i have 1 `Parent` class, but like 20 `Child` classes. for the vast majority of the children, the `foo` should be `false`. However, `Child1` (and a few others) is the weird one with `foo = true;`.

what is the most proper OO Design and yet code effecient way to do this?

Comment: You forgot a type, `boolean`. Also, only methods and classes can be abstract. Also, do that in the constructor.

Comment: What's the point of this? Can't you just initiate it to the correct value when you create the subclass?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis oh, thanx for the catch. and yes, hence i wrote it in the comments that it doesn't compile. good call on the constructor part.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel sorry if my question might have been confusing, but what is your suggestion? I was wondering if there's an OOP way of doing what i'm trying to describe. basically, the constraint is only a minority of the subclasses should do something different, to a common/overridable variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a constructor or two:

```
public abstract class Parent {
    protected boolean foo;
    protected Parent() {
        this(false); // initialize foo to default value
    }
    protected Parent(boolean fooValue) {
        this.foo = fooValue;
    }
}

public class Child1 extends Parent {
    public Child1() {
        super(true);
    }
}

public class Child2 extends Parent {
    // no explicit super(boolean) call in c'tor gives foo the default value
}
```

Comment: i actually really like this - you force the variable initial value in the child's constructor.

Answer (score 2):

First, instance variables cannot be `abstract`, only methods can.

To have overriding behavior, you need methods.  I would define a method, say, `isFoo` in `Parent` that is defined to return `false`.  No subclasses would need to override it, except for the "weird one"(s), which can override it to return `true`.

Alternatively, you can have a subclass of `Parent` called `WeirdOne` (doesn't have to be that name of course).  The only thing it does is override `isFoo` to return `true`.  Then `Child1`  and any other "weird" classes subclass `WeirdOne`.  This way, it's only overridden in one place.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to do like this

```
public abstract class Parent {

    protected boolean check = false;

}

public class Child extends Parent 
{
    public void method()
    {
        this.check=true;
    }

}
```

// You can put it in constructor also

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extend the `Parent` class using `Child1` class, you have to type:

```
public class Child1 extends Parent {

}
```

About the `foo` parameter, you can't set it `abstract` since is not a function (that is, only functions can be declared `abstract`). You can, however, override it in subclasses.

```
public abstract class Parent {
    protected boolean foo = false;
}

public class Child1 extends Parent {
    @Override
    protected boolean foo = true;
}
```

Comment: This will not change the `Parent.foo` variable. Your annotation will be rejected by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a field then.  Look at this combination of classes:

```
public abstract class Vehicle {
    public abstract boolean isAerial();
}

public abstract Flyer extends Vehicle {
    @Override
    public final boolean isAerial() {
        return true;
    }
}
// Add Airplane, Helicopter, Dirigible, Rocket, etc.

public abstract Terrestrial extends Vehicle {
    @Override
    public final boolean isAerial() {
        return false;
    }
}
// Add Car, Truck, Boat, Bicycle, etc.
```